# Why does cold water leak when hot water is turned on in bathroom sink?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, water, faucet, sink

Before I try to repair this, I want to understand what's going on so I don't fix the wrong thing or cause a larger leak in the bathroom sink.

Our house was built about 20 yrs ago (about 1998).  When you turn on the hot water, for some reason, water starts leaking from the base of the cold water faucet.  Why would this happen?  I can understand if I turn on the cold water and it leaks from the faucet but not this.

I was going to change the cartridge in the cold water to see if this fixes it but I'd like to know why this funky behavior is occurring before I start doing something I shouldn't be doing and causing a bigger problem.

Comment: Does water leak from the cold side when it's on?

Comment: @HazardousGlitch, thanks for your interest in helping me. No, if I turn on just the cold water, it doesn't leak from the faucet base.  The funny thing is it doesn't always leak water on the cold faucet when I turn on the hot water.  Not sure why it's intermittent, or why the cold faucet leaks when the hot water is turned on.

Comment: It seems this has an answer, however, for future readers. If there is a base plate covering both water taps, it could be that the hot side is leaking, but the base plate is sealed well enough to keep the water in there, however, there's a gap on the cold side allowing the water to come out on _that_ side below the plate making it _appear_ that it's leaking on the cold side.

Comment: what is the leaked water temperature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cold water cartridge could have a weird worn down spot on it that is causing the leak. I'd try the replacement like you were thinking to see if it resolves the issue.